# I can not change the date format in django drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have drf model which is containe DateField. That field default format is "YYYY-MM-DD" just i want to convert "DD-MM-YYYY" how can is possible.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from.models import SpaUser
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer
import datetime
from rest_framework.settings import api_settings



class SpaUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    date_joined = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    birthdate = serializers.DateField(format="%d-%m-%Y", input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',])
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If it is universal, in your settings file add `"DATE_INPUT_FORMATS"` to `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings like:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],
    ...
}
```

for more details check http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting

Comment: Thanks you.  here my mistake         "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: %, d, -, %, m, -, %, Y."

Answer (score 8):

To have it correctly work, `input_formats` is the argument you need to assign the format needed, `format` is the output format

```
birthdate = serializers.DateField(input_formats=['%d-%m-%Y',])
```

or you can set the default input format in your settings

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    ("%d-%m-%Y"),
]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have this error:  "birthdate": [
        "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
    ]

Comment: I really tried everything.
it's been over 48h that I'm stuck

Comment: Please help me. Thanks you

Comment: worked for me fantastic. I was wondering how do I include the time as well?

Answer (score 2):

By combining all your solutions, it works

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": "%d-%m-%Y", doesn't works
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': [("%d-%m-%Y"),],it works
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Comment: `("%d-%m-%Y")` and `"%d-%m-%Y"` are same, `>>> (1)==1` returns `True`

Answer (score 2):

We have to differentiate between all these:

1. `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`

   To specify the date format for the input in `POST` request `API`.
2. `DATETIME_FORMAT`

   To specify the DateTime format for serialized data like with `GET` request.
3. `DATE_FORMAT`

   To specify the Date format for serialized data like with `GET` request.

And this is an example of how to use these settings in the `settings.py` file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATE_INPUT_FORMATS': ["%Y-%m-%d %H", ],
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H',
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H'
}
```

**Note:** You should use these settings just if you want your serializer to have the same data or DateTime format.

But in case you have changed in some field you can just change the `format` for that field and here is an example of how to do like this:

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super(YourSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        representation['created_at'] = instance.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H)
        return representation
```

Or in a similar way

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Comment: Useful answer!, can you tell me how to include every possible date_input_formats?

"*" did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

From DRF documentation regarding [DateField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield)

> Format strings may either be Python [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) formats which explicitly
>   specify the format, or the special string 'iso-8601', which indicates
>   that ISO 8601 style dates should be used. (eg '2013-01-29')

So in your case format should be

```
format="%d-%m-%Y"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have this error:  "birthdate": [
        "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY[-MM[-DD]]."
    ]

Comment: I really tried everything.
it's been over 48h that I'm stuck

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Flexi why your question is deleted I need the answers of that question

Answer (score 1):

Although this thread is quite old, I found it when trying to solve a similar problem. Although the responses didn't give me the entire answer, they did push me to simply read DRF's quite helpful documentation on the topic:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#date-and-time-formatting

In my case, I am building a events calendar using Vuetify's v-calendar, Vue JS, and DRF. The v-calendar requires the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM, and prefers a string. I could simply store the string in my DB, but I preferred to store the datetime fields in native Python formatting for server-side processing should I ever need them. So, in my settings.py file, I added the following to my REST_FRAMEWORK setting:

```
'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS': ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',],
'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
```

The first one takes a list (hence the brackets and comma), the second just takes a string. Then, in my serializer, I use:

start = serializers.DateTimeField()

On the front end, I take in the dates as the string objects, pass them to the calendar for display, and it works. When POSTing data, I simply pass them back in that same string format, and the DRF serializer encodes them as native Python for storage.

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py include:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {  
    'DATE_FORMAT': '%d-%m-%Y'
}
```