# How to change example format value of datefield in drf yasg (swagger)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

Hello im using drf yasg library to implement swagger in my django based app. I have changed the date format in settings.py file to look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DATE_INPUT_FORMATS": ["%d-%m-%Y"],
}
```

Now when I try to test my endpoint in the swagger then I get example of date field in wrong format:

```
{
  "birth_date": "2021-04-27",
}
```

And when I try to execute the request I receive the error:

```
{
  "birth_date": [
    "Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: DD-MM-YYYY."
  ]
}
```

What is expected to receive but it's annoying to change the example date each time I want to use it.
Any tips how to achieve the same format in the swagger example?

Comment: I think the OAS doesn't recommend/support anything other than *ISO* format ([see this](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/))

Comment: Look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660580/i-can-not-change-the-date-format-in-django-drf